# TSP and Lin-Kernighan algorithm from primm graph

Tags: optimization, graph, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to code a TSP problem. I already have the minimal weight graph thanks to Primm algo, I also read that Lin-Kernighan algorithm could be constructed from this graph but can't see how to make it.

Is anyone could explain to me how to perform that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct an eulerian circuit from your minimum spanning tree and then you can remove overlapping paths (x-cross connection between 2 edges) with Lin Kernigan.